# urwid + websockets + asyncio -- server / client

Tags: websocket, server, client, python-asyncio, urwid

I want to make a server/client program based on websockets (server+client) and a urwid user interface at client side.

The issue I face is that I keep on getting "Task exception was never retrieved"...
I works, but it is not clean....

My server:

```
import asyncio, websockets, random, json

connected = set()

##########################
# end-less loop routines
##########################

async def handle_read_external_data():
  # now sumulated by an asyncio sleep of 1 second and random generator
  await asyncio.sleep(1)
  data = {'value': (random.random() * 0.4) - 0.2 + 40}
  return data

async def broadcast_task():
  global connected
  while True:
    data = await handle_read_external_data()
    data_json = json.dumps(data)
    print ("len:", len(connected))
    if connected != set():
      try:
        await asyncio.wait([ws.send(data_json) for ws in connected])
      except Exception as e:
        print (e)

##########################
# websockets
##########################

async def consumer_handler(websocket, path):
  global connected
  # Register.
  connected.add(websocket)
  try:
    async for message in websocket:
      print (message)
  except Exception as e:
    print ("Unregister websocket")
    connected.remove(websocket)

##########################
# Asyncio event loop
##########################

def start_event_loop():
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  tasks = asyncio.gather(
        broadcast_task(),
        websockets.serve(consumer_handler, '0.0.0.0', 8765),
    )
  try:
    loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
  except Exception:
    print("exception consumed")
  except BaseException:
    print("caught BaseException!")
    raise
  finally:
    loop.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_event_loop()
```

My client:

```
import asyncio, websockets, json, urwid

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
evl = urwid.AsyncioEventLoop(loop=loop)
urwid_loop = None
tasks = None

txt = urwid.Text(u"Hello World")
fill = urwid.Filler(txt, 'top')

def show_or_exit(key):
    if key in ('q', 'Q'):
      global tasks
      tasks.cancel()
      raise urwid.ExitMainLoop()
    return key

async def consumer_handler():
    async with websockets.connect('ws://localhost:8765') as websocket:
      async for message in websocket:
        data = json.loads(message)
        txt.set_text ("data: {}".format (data['value']))


def main ():
  global urwid_loop, tasks, loop, evl

  urwid_loop = urwid.MainLoop(fill, event_loop=evl, unhandled_input=show_or_exit)
  urwid_loop.start()

  tasks = asyncio.gather(consumer_handler())

  try:
      loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
  except asyncio.CancelledError:
      pass

  urwid_loop.stop()
  loop.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I start the server I got:

```
len: 0
len: 0
len: 0
...
```

So far so good.
When I start the client the the server shows me:

```
len: 0
len: 0
len: 1
len: 1
len: 1
...
```

At the moment I press CTRL+C at the client I got:

```
len: 1
Unregister websocket
len: 0
```

This is the wanted behavior, except that in the client I got an exception and my terminal is 'corrupt' as it still in 'urwid' modus.

The clean exit, by hitting the Q button, it yields in a clean exit for the client, and the terminal is ok.
At server side, there is then the message "*Task exception was never retrieved*", and the "connected" variable still holds the closed websocket.

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<WebSocketCommonProtocol.send() done, defined at ><path-to-python-install>/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py:325> exception=ConnectionClosed('WebSocket connection is closed: code = 1000 (OK), no reason',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path-to-python-install>/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 334, in send
    yield from self.ensure_open()
  File "<path-to-python-install>/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 470, in ensure_open
    raise ConnectionClosed(self.close_code, self.close_reason)
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed: WebSocket connection is closed: code = 1000 (OK), no reason
len: 1
Task exception was never retrieved
...
```

Anyone a clue?